# Having trouble using requests for urls

Tags: python, python-requests, anaconda

I simply wrote the following code to play around with the Requests library

```
requests tests
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

but I keep getting the same error message, even if I use `from requests import *`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dvanderknaap/Desktop/Organized/CS/My_Python_Programs/requests.py", line 3, in <module>
import requests
File "/Users/dvanderknaap/Desktop/Organized/CS/My_Python_Programs/requests.py", line 5, in <module>
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I've tried reinstalling requests using `pip install requests`, but the output is:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I think the problem is that it is installed in my python3.5 library but I am using python2.7, but I'm not sure how to fix that. 
Advice?

Comment: and to install it for python 2.7 do `pip2.7 install requests`

Comment: isn't the program file `...CS/My_Python_Programs/requests.py` already named `requests.py` ? as per @Kevin's answer (now deleted)

Comment: Yeah I changed it after that comment but that didn't fix the problem. I followed your advice and now i get the InsecurePlatformWarning error

Answer (score 8):

First, rename your file My_Python_Programs/requests.py to something else than requests.py. It is importing itself instead of the requests module.

Your python 2.7 may or may not already have the requests package installed. If not, you can install it with

```
pip2.7 install requests
```

Comment: I did this but now I am getting an InsecurePlatformWarning error and a SNIMissingWarning error

Comment: So the problem is fixed. Now you have a different problem. What is the full error message?

Comment: (1/2) Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 315
    SNIMissingWarning
SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.

Comment: (2/2) Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 120
    InsecurePlatformWarning
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

Comment: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning <--- have you read the links helpfully provided in the error messages?

Comment: In my experience, the section [OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#pyopenssl) disappear the error messages. <br/>
 
`pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 cryptography`  


`import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl`  
`urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()`

Comment: From the docs on SNIMissingWarning: Certain Python distributions (specifically, versions of Python earlier than 2.7.9) and older OpenSSLs have restrictions that prevent them from using the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension. This can cause unexpected behaviour when making some HTTPS requests, usually causing the server to present the a TLS certificate that is not valid for the website you’re trying to access.

If you encounter this warning, it is strongly recommended that you upgrade to a newer Python version, or that you use pyOpenSSL as described in the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section.

Comment: SNIMissingWarning:  pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expecting that there is a proper wrapper for your `pip` with a version number, use the `pip` **module** of your desired Python interpreter:

```
% python2.7 -mpip install requests
```